# Return XML and JSON response from loopback Framework

Tags: json, xml, loopbackjs, strongloop

As mentioned in
[Returning XML in response from Loopback Remote Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171438/returning-xml-in-response-from-loopback-remote-method).
I tried to enable XML in config.json
but it gives me error for json remote method

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 21 at column 12: PCDATA invalid Char value 23
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

0 37.77262899999999 -122.25185 true B ObjectID
```

Any idea why?

How can I return XML for some remote methods and JSON for others? Where to set Headers for remote methods?

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? I have the same probem - I need to return XML from one specific remote method, while keeping JSON response in the others